# What does skew mean in the context of performance engineering

Tags: performance

This word is being used in software performance discussions. I searched on google for its meaning but no success.

Comment: One usage on this page: http://192.9.162.55/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPMeasurement.fm.html

Comment: Are you talking about *Won't **skew** results*?

Comment: yes. @Blender also, I have heard: we want to measure the skew of xyz. What will that mean?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've meant performance event skid. In general according to [Intel's manual](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/analyze-performance/custom-analysis/custom-analysis-options/hardware-event-list/hardware-event-skid.html)

> Event skid is the recording of an event not exactly on the code line that caused the event.

For better understanding and example see [this article](https://easyperf.net/blog/2018/08/29/Understanding-performance-events-skid) by Denis Bakhvalov.

Answer (score 0):

*Measurement* of skew almost certainly indicates the usual meaning in statistics, the third moment about the mean (zero for symmetric, negative for skew to the left, positive for skew to the right).  See http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/skew for less formal usages.