# cache miss even if both operands are registers?

Tags: perf

I'm using perf(version 5.4.73) to record cache-misses event, and perf report shows something like:

```
Samples: 285k of 'cache-misses'
...
0.37   vmovq   (%rcx), %xmm5
71.09  mov     0x30(%rbx), %ecx
2.15   cmp     %eax,%ecx  //both operands are registers, why cache miss here?
0.14   jne     242
```

My question is why there is cache miss event(2.15%) for `cmp %eax,%ecx` even if both operands are registers?

Comment: My first guess would be an miss on the instruction itself.

Comment: @MSalters I've tried record `L1-dcache-loads-misses` event and the phenomenon is similar, it shows dcache miss on instruction of which both operands are registers

Comment: Sounds like a case of skew, where sometimes the event spills onto the next instruction.  (Although more often *most* of the counts get skewed).  Without PEBS (Intel) for precise events, an interrupt has to fire to record a sample.  Maybe try with `-e mem_load_retired.l1_miss:p` to force a precise event.  (That's an event on my Skylake CPU; IDK what CPU architecture you're using.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Could you explain more about what is "skew" and when/why it happens? I've tried `-e mem_load_retired.l1_miss:p`, the results seem more rational, but I can still see something like `99.92  test %esi %esi `, `0.07  cmp %eax $ecx`. I'm using Cascade Lake intel CPU and I've also tested it(cache-misses event)  on AMD EPYC(Milan)

Comment: https://easyperf.net/blog/2018/08/29/Understanding-performance-events-skid / [What does skew mean in the context of performance engineering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15169480) / [How does perf record (or other profilers) pick which instruction to count as costing time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69351189).  IDK why you'd be getting any counts for a mem_load_retired event on an ALU instruction no memory operands, though.  `cmp`/`test` can macro-fuse, but only with a `jcc`, not memory-indirect jmp (which doesn't read FLAGS).

Comment: Also related: [What does this sentence mean in the context of perf tool: "Supports address when precise (Precise event)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71629004) / [Perf shows L1-dcache-load-misses in a block with no memory access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63251365)